# How can I set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH in visual studio 2022?

Tags: c++, cmake, pytorch, visual-studio-2022

I want to use Pytorch c++ in Visual studio 2022 ,that is why I need to set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH in Visual studio ,but I can't it.I tried to do it following the tutorial https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/installing.html ,but i failed .For some reason it doesn't work.I haven't errors , but my cmake doesn't see the way to libtorch

I want gain the opportunity use Pytorch c++

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/customize-cmake-settings?view=msvc-170](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/customize-cmake-settings?view=msvc-170)

Answer (score 0):

I've used with success this in one of the `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH C:\\ThePath)
```